# Golang: cannot install package zvelo/ttlru

Tags: go, package

I would like to use [zvelo/ttlru](https://github.com/zvelo/ttlru) and have successfully `go get` this package from github.

**Problem:**

The following error occurs, when I try to `go run` my go program, that contains the `import "github.com/zvelo/ttlru"`:

> go_server.go:8:2: code in directory
>   /home/.../work_go/src/github.com/zvelo/ttlru expects import
>   "zvelo.io/ttlru"

What is wrong here? I don't see any `zvelo.io/ttlru` imports anywhere.

Comment: As you can see this in https://github.com/zvelo/ttlru/blob/master/ttlru.go#L12 packages expects to be imported as "zvelo.io/ttlru" so you must import it that way. No arguing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try go getting and importing "zvelo.io/ttlru"

Comment: There is no such repo in github or I don't have access

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [README.md](https://github.com/zvelo/ttlru) and the error message, import from zvelo.io/ttlru and not github.com/zvelo/ttlru.

Make sure to use `go get zvelo.io/ttlru`

You will then find the source of the package in `/home/.../work_go/src/zvelo.io/ttlru/`.